# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities' when using splinter to webscrape

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I am running into an issue with my code and I'm not sure why this is happening as I didn't change anything and it was working fine last night.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from splinter import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

import requests

executable_path = {'executable_path': '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'}
browser = Browser('chrome', executable_path, headless=False)

browser.visit(url)
```

I want to scrape a website (which I've already assigned to the variable url). Like I said, last night it ran with no problem with this. I currently have the latest version of chromedriver.exe and my PATH is in the correct place.

the error I'm running to now is :

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

On the browser = Browser('chrome', executable_path, headless=False)

When I try to change executable_path to **executable_path on that line, I get a PATH error.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. (I'm a newbie and have only been coding for 7 months & web scraped 2 times prior to this). Thank you!

ANSWERED: changed the line to 
`browser = Browser('chrome')`

Comment: You should post the full error message including the stack trace, along with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my error by just changing my code to:

```
browser = Browser('chrome')
```

I'm not sure why this works better, but it fixed my error!